# How can I change Blender's Scripts Path in preferences with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, customization, path

I tried scripting with Blender but I am stuck on this problem.

I want so change the Scripts Folder from the Blender Preferences (Preferences → File Paths → Scripts )

[image: screenshot of preferences with File Paths tab open]

Is it possible to do this with Python in Blender directly?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preferences are found in `bpy.context.preferences`.  Mostly the name of the next field match the name in the tab, roughly.  You can check this by going to the python console and typing `dir(bpy.context.preferences)`.  It will print something like this:

```
['__doc__', '__module__', '__slots__', 'active_section', 'addons', 'app_template', 'autoexec_paths', 'bl_rna', 'edit', 'experimental', 'filepaths', 'inputs', 'is_dirty', 'keymap', 'rna_type', 'studio_lights', 'system', 'themes', 'ui_styles', 'use_preferences_save', 'version', 'view']
```

From this we see that `filepaths` is the right field.  To find the actual name for the scripts directory, make sure you have enabled *Developer Extras* and *Python Tooltips* in Preferences → *Interface* and hover over the *Scripts* input field.  You'll see something like this:

[image: Tooltip for scripts]

Since we know from above that "PreferencesFilePaths" is represented by `bpy.context.preferences.filepaths`  We simply add `script_directory`:

```
bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.script_directory
```

It is a string variable, but remember that in Python backslash is a string escape character, so if you're providing windows filepaths, you have to either use the 'r' form of a string (r"C:\tmp") or escape the backslashes ("C:\\tmp")

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! and thanks for the good explanation, this was very helpful.

Comment: I tried different things but none of them worked to write the variable just to read it... But yours is working fine :) 
bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.script_directory = "C:\\tmp"
And its just as simple as that, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Just posting a comment for anyone who stumbles on this post and is working with Blender 3.6+. Updates to the API mean that the user can now set multiple custom script directories and .script_directory has been deprecated in favour of .script_directories. The first directory path in that list (if set) can now be referenced with:

```
bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.script_directories[0].directory
```

Alternatively you still reference the default scripts path with:

```
bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS')
```